# integrity violation while seeding

Tags: mysql, laravel, foreign-keys

This is my seeder class below

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class RequestTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
public function run()
{
     $faker = Faker\Factory::create();

     for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){
        DB::table('requests')->insert([
            "location_id"=>$faker->numberBetween(1,5),
            "level_id"=>$faker->numberBetween(0,1),
            "subject_id"=>$faker->numberBetween(0,1),
            "first_name"=>$faker->firstName,
            "last_name"=>$faker->lastName,
            "contact"=>$faker->unique()->phoneNumber,
            "email"=>$faker->unique()->email,
            "description"=>$faker->text(1000),
            ]);
     }
}
}
```

Here is my levelseeder class:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class SubjectTableSeeder extends Seeder

{

public function run()
{


$faker = Faker\Factory::create();

    for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
    {
        DB::table('subjects')->insert([
            "name"=>$faker->text(5),
            ]);
    }
}
}
```

while i try to seed from the command i get:

```
 [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tutor`.`requests`, CONSTRAINT `requests_level_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`level_id`) REFERENCES `levels` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

i also checked my subject seeder class.But i could not find the error.[This are my seeder class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnfLF.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert a `level_id` that references a row in the `level` table that doesn't exist!

In order for this to work your `level` table needs to be seeded with at least 5 records with the `id` of 1,2,3,4,5

If you are doing this, maybe the order of your seeders is wrong. Make sure the `LevelTableSeeder` runs before the `RequestTableSeeder`.

Further, it seems that `subject_id` will most likely fail next. This is intended behavior when using **[foreign keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)** which are used to ensure database integrity.

Comment: I inserted value in level table but still the command shows the same problem.

Comment: Sorry, from the limited information you provided this is the best answer I can give. Double check your seeders are running in the right order and double check the error message is identical.

Comment: Thank you for your answers .Finally i found my mistake. :D

Comment: What was the mistake?